# Set DataGridTextColumn MaxLength property dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to set the `DataGridTextColumn.MaxLength` property dynamically based on an integer variable. Therefore, in some cases it should be 4 and in others it should be 5.

I tried it with a binding on the `MaxLength` value like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="{Binding MaxTextBoxLength, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

```
public int MaxTextBoxLength
{
    get => maxTextBoxLength;
    set
    {
        maxTextBoxLength= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `MaxTextBoxLength` property defined?

Comment: @mm8 It's defined in the view model. Your answer works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iF `MaxTextBoxLength` is defined in the view model, you could bind to it using the `RelativeSource` property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="MaxLength"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.MaxTextBoxLength, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```